# Error: 1>0 and print("yes")

Tags: python, python-2.x

Python:

```
1>0 and print("yes")
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax at 'print'

Could anyone tell why? Thanks!

Comment: @RongNguyen It is actually the exact opposite of it, I believe :)

Comment: People should seriously stop jumping at every opportunity to state that a question is a "possible duplicate".

Comment: @LeeWhite The problem is related to the question i reported, seriously!

Comment: @thefourtheye The answer is similar for both :-)

Comment: you are combining boolean and a print statement.   Interpreter cannot figure what you intended too, Neither can we if you do not explain what it is.  This squestion is probably not suited to this site See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask.   Also try an online python guide.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Python 2 print is a statement and it cannot used as an expression.

To use the Python 3's print function in Python 2 you need to import it first:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> 1>0 and print("yes")
  File "<ipython-input-2-0714eacbdec3>", line 1
    1>0 and print("yes")
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> 1>0 and print("yes")
yes
```

Comment: I'm using python 2.6. Following your answer, I have made it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.* print is a statement and you cannot use statements in (boolean) expressions because they do not return a value.